# Bash, get normal strings to behave like $@ vs $*

Tags: bash, quoting

**Solution:**

I eventually got it with bash arrays, my solution is [here](https://github.com/JoshCheek/thread_order/blob/c4026fb7e7697e011b3bf8e02217ddb34a118b60/spec/run#L45-56).

---

**Question:**

In bash, I can have a function whose arguments have spaces, and I can use `$@` or `$*` to get the quoting right:

```
$ _() { ruby -e 'p ARGV' "$@"; }; _ 'a b c' '1 2 3'
["a b c", "1 2 3"]

$ _() { ruby -e 'p ARGV' "$*"; }; _ 'a b c' '1 2 3'
["a b c 1 2 3"]
```

I'm building up a string where the arguments could have spaces, and would like it to behave like the `"$@"`, is there a way to do this?

```
$ arg1="a b c"
$ arg2="1 2 3"
$ args="$arg2 $arg2"

# behaves like $*, but I want it to behave like $@
$ ruby -e 'p ARGV' "$args"
["1 2 3 1 2 3"]

$ ruby -e 'p ARGV' $args
["1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3"]
```

Comment: If you're building it up as a string, this doesn't seem possible - you can't distinguish between a "real" space and the space you're inserting. Why not make the arguments an array of strings?

Comment: You can always set a new $@ using the "set" command.  ... Or use a bash array (not portable to posix sh)

Comment: @ChrisHayes I looked at it, but I wasn't sure how to manipulate the array, and I had a sense that this was a new feature that might not exist for the environment my code runs in (I haven't researched this yet). First answer looks promising, though, so I'll explore it.

Comment: @technosaurus I tried that with variations on the `set` builtin for probably 20+ minutes. [This](https://gist.github.com/JoshCheek/6e62cb8cfede7653597c) is basically how far I got.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Absolutely, use arrays.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

```
$ args=()
$ args+=("a b c")
$ args+=("1 2 3")

$ ruby -e 'p ARGV' "${args[@]}"
["a b c", "1 2 3"]
```

Comment: Hmm. Took me a long time to figure out how to translate this to my example. My array isn't a literal, I'm building it programatically. Can you confirm that this is how you push args onto an array named "a"?  `a[${#a[@]}]="some arg"` because I couldn't find anything better, and while I mostly understand it, it's still very opaque and unintuitive to me. Also, they don't take this approach in the docs you linked to, section #5 uses `set` (which I had also tried, but it didn't work for me -- only obvious difference is that I was putting the args at the front).

Comment: In other words, this is what I came up with: `args=(); args[${#args[@]}]="a b c"; args[${#args[@]}]="1 2 3"; ruby -e 'p ARGV' "${args[@]}";` Is that how you would do it? Seems like there should be a `push` command or something.

Comment: The linked article first brings up arrays in section 3. Section 5 has a link to another article with more information about arrays. `a+=("some arg")`